# Why does change in tension of a vibrating string result in infinite acceleration of an atom at the transition point?

Tags: waves, vibrations

[image]Consider an infinite uniform vibrating string centred at $x=0$ and extends from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ whose tension is to be changed at x=0.Instead of just changing the tension directly we introduce a massless ring.The boundary between the two halves of the string(at $x=0$)is a massless ring,and this ring encircles a ﬁxed frictionless pole.And our professor just said without an explanation,that if we just change the tension at $x=0$ "WITHOUT INTRODUCING THIS RING",then there will be infinite acceleration of the atom of the string at $x=0$.so we have to introduce this ring.Why will it the acceleration of the atom at x=0 happen due to change in tension?

Comment: Can you include a picture of the set up. I am not fully grasping this. Also, is the string centered at $x=0$?

Comment: The picture has been given in the post now.The string is centred at x=0 and extends to infinity on both sides.

Comment: Does the ring constrain the motion of the string?  That would prevent infinite acceleration.

Comment: Yes.But why will the infinite acceleration occur in the first place if we just change the tension at x=0 without introducing the ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the discontinuity of the string line at $x=0$.

There is probably an assumption that the stretched string, without a ring in the middle, assumes the shape of a triangle. If so, the tension forces on both sides of the atom at $x=0$ would have finite angles and, therefore, there would be a finite resulting force component pulling the atom toward the resting position, i.e., along the y axis.

Obviously, a finite force acting on an atom could result in a "close to" infinite acceleration.

The ring presumably eliminates the discontinuity, which makes y components of the tension forces near the contact points infinitely small, preventing infinite acceleration.

Comment: What is meant by "string assumes the shape of a triangle?"And is there any other way to solve the problem of string with different tensions?

Comment: @Man_57  My understanding was that direct changing of tension at x=0 meant that someone pulled the string at x=0 in y direction thus creating an angle with a vertex at x=0 and two halves of string as two lines forming angle. This two lines form a triangle with the horizontal line corresponding to the resting position of string, but the use of word triangle, I agree, could be misleading. Besides that detail,  looking at the drawings you've added, I am starting to doubt that I understood this setup correctly. Perhaps, you should add some details, i.e., what is meant by changing tension.